# How to get my icons and banner image to align.

Tags: html, css

First off, here is what I am working on: https://copyservices.myprintdesk.net/DSF/SmartStore.aspx?6xni2of2cF08a9yXIbxQJGevO4cxxJ4eJOqKCy4/KENOCxKyWGDKi0aXSIZd5QbD#!/Storefront

This is a work project, and I have no say in which web design service we use; we have to use this one as it is already paid for in full, despite how finicky and hard to control it us. It is called Digital Storefront.

Like it says in my thread title, my banner image and my icons below in the main body of the homepage do not always align. Sometimes it does, but it all depends on the width of the browser. All of our clients will be using a super wide browser on these super widescreen monitors we have at our college's campus, so its a big deal.

On our site settings, it has us define how many columns of icons we desire. In there I have it set to 3. It seems to do no good. On the Digital Storefront help forum I have a thread here about this: http://dsfforums.efi.com/showthread.php?1469-Challenges-Getting-Banner-Image-and-Category-Icons-to-Display-Full-Size-amp-Align ... and as you can see, the two experts I'm conversing with there tell me I need to do something coding-wise. There are multiple coding pages that we are able to edit, but since these icons are what DSF considers to be "Categories" I went to the coding page called Categories.

To attempt this, I did some brief research on coding, and I concluded that this is most likely what I was needing:

[quote]

[/quote]

and added 2  tags at the bottom of the coding page to complete the html commands. The only thing this did was a bad thing; it caused a huge indent to all my rows of category icons.

The width of the site banner image is 960 pixels, which consequently is the exact width of three of those icon columns. If you make the banner image longer than 960 pixels, it automatically resizes it to 960 pixels wide, so making a banner image the width of 4 icon columns is not the way to go.

Another big factor in this: You cannot go back a step coding wise. In other words, you can't revert to the way you previously had it. Tech support, as well as this online forum for DSF I have will not help you if you somehow ruin things or do something destructive to your site, so changes to the coding pages are not recommended unless you are 1000% certain that what you are doing is right, which sucks for me because I don't have much of a feel for coding outside of super basic things. Its unfortunate this is reality, but like I said I had no control over this upon being hired.

Any other info I could include to you guys that would make helping me easier? Based on what you've read on my problem, so you know what I was doing wrong with my coding attempt, or perhaps does someone know a better method than what I'm doing?

Thanks a bunch for any help you guys are able to provide. Hope your Summers are going well.

Comment: Welcome! Your question seems to be lacking in details, making it hard to answer. Please take the time to provide a snippet of HTML, and enough CSS to demonstrate the issue you are having. In other words, try to make a small demo page (HTML + CSS) that has the problem. Once you do that, you will have a question that has a better chance of being answered by your colleagues here.

Comment: Here is what I added:

Comment: Hello again. I can't get to the DSFforums post without logging in. Could you copy over enough that question so we can have specific HTML to look at?